# Heroku error node, mongo, react (Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mongoose

This is the first time I deploy an app on Heroku. It runs fine locally, but once I try opening the app on Heroku I get an 'Application Error'. I will add the code files below.

**Procfile**

```
web: npm run start
```

**index.js**

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";

const app = express();
dotenv.config();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.use("/posts", postRoutes);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello to Memories API');
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`))
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);
```

**.env**

```
CONNECTION_URL = mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.a0uak.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "heroku": "^7.47.7",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.8",
    "n": "^7.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

I also confirmed my IP address is whitelisted on the MongoDB site.

Hopefully, someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above `error` clearly mentioned that `web process` took a longer time than `60 second` to bind the assigned `$PORT`. This `error` generally occurs when the process being unable to reach the external resources such as `DB`. However, the default `boot` time is `60 second`. But some application requires more time to `boot`. You can try by increasing the app's boot timeout. [Go to this.](https://tools.heroku.support/limits/boot_timeout)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me with this, and sorry for the delayed response. I have raised the boot time to 150 seconds which is the maximum time limit on Heroku and the same issue continues.

Comment: type this `command` into your `procfile` once `bundle exec thin start -p $PORT`

Comment: You are a freaking genius !! That solved my issue! I would like to understand a little more about what that does if you could explain it would be great.